# If we can share ext4 file system then why do we need NFS file system?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, ext4, file-sharing

I understood that NFS is a file system which can be shared and accessed over network by Linux machine.
And ext4 is another file system which is supported by Linux machines. I thought ext4 is a file system which are used when the storage devices are directly attached.

However, I've seen that even ext4 file systems on another system is accessed over network after mounting.
I'm saying this in the basis that when I run

```
df -Th .
```

I've seen the file system type to be shown as ext4

So if even ext4 file system can be accessed over network then why NFS file system is considered something particularly as a file system accessible over network?

Comment: Pretty sure you're using one of NFS, samba, sshfs, etc. in "ext4 file systems on another system is accessed over network"

Comment: Another way would be for the block device itself to be exported over the network (e.g., iSCSI), but then ext4 knows nothing about the network in that case either. Show us the details of the relevant output.

Comment: NFS is more like a protocol for sharing filesystems. While ext4 I'd really a traditional filesystem -- a way to organize data on a disk.

Comment: I misinterpreted the configuration on our work environment.
I knew that a particular directory was not a local one and when i execute the command - df -Th ., it was showing it as an ext4 file-system. But the thing in this case was, the directory on which i ran the df -Th . command had a local directory mounted, which in turn has a nfs file system mounted.

Apologies to all for misinterpreting and posting the question here. I will close the question.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I've seen that even ext4 file systems on another system is accessed over network after mounting.

This needs explanation.

No, by itself ext4 filesystem is **not** network transparent, it's just a method of storing and retrieving data from a block device.

Comment: 1. Updated the question. 2. What do you mean by not network transparent?